# MongoDB - yielded operation

Tags: mongodb

Doing a load test on a setup having mongo as the database, I noticed that mongo frequently logged messages of this type all belonging to the same operation:

```
Thu May 16 20:44:20.101 [conn3] command voterdb.$cmd command: { group: { ns: "vote",
$reduce: function ( curr, result ) { result.count++; }, cond: { p: "59a0f4cd-8c0c-49c4-
8a11-0e1ac6d89c4a" }, initial: { count: 0 }, out: "inline", key: { p: 1, q: 1, a: 1 } }  
} ntoreturn:1 keyUpdates:0 numYields: 2 locks(micros) r:228316 reslen:876 136ms
```

the application is simple, I add documents to a collection and with every document added I need an update of how many belong to each type. so a grouping operation is performed where documents in this collection are grouped by type.

What I noticed was that when the test finished, mongo kept displaying these messages, and processing these grouping queries several minutes after the test was over (meaning queries were being serviced with a delay).

I read that mongo is  writer greedy and I also read about yielded operations. Am i right to assume that inserts are getting precedence over grouping and the grouping operations are being yielded resulting in post-test processing?

Comment: It seems like your questions are all answered on this page: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/concurrency/ Is there something that wasn't covered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MongoDB utilizes readers and writer locks on DBs, which means that a writer holds an exclusive lock on a DB while multiple readers can share a lock. In order to prevent long running operations from holding up writer and reader queues, MongoDB supports yielding. The primary approach is around the idea that in memory ops should be served up quickly first and not have to wait on ops that go to disk. Below is a link that provides more specifics around yielding, and profiling stats.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/concurrency/#faq-concurrency-yielding
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/database-profiler/

Also a couple of thoughts on the description of your application. I would have to go into detail to specifically recommend the best approach, but I sense there is a more efficient design to what you are doing.

1. Use Aggregation Framework vs Map Reduce: it appears like you might be using a MR process to perform your tally. The aggregation framework has significantly less overhead and will almost always be faster.
2. If it turns out that you're just doing a count, see if you can simply do a db.collection.find({..}).count() as this will be extremely fast. Counts are cached in indexes.
3. Lastly, do you need to perform an aggregation on every document inserted? There are various options. For example, you much just want to increment ($inc) some counter, or perform the aggregation periodically in the background. To perfect scenario would be where it is viable to store a document at the granularity of a type, which will allow you to do both your tally and insert in one op.